# How to identify each circles in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api, circle

By the Google Maps Drawing API, I can create lot of circle and other shapes. addListner method helps to get the radius, latitude and longitude of the circle. Now I want to identify each circle for storing its coordinates and radius. The intention is when user clicks in circles, all these values stored in the input button for each circles and submit to database.

How can I move forward ?

[image]